# Change scopes about CalendarApp.getallcalendards() method

Tags: google-apps-script, publishing

In my codebase I use CalendarApp.getallcalendar() to have all user's calendars.

This metod has got this Authorization:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly
https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds
```

In my script's proprieties, scopes about calendar is https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar
So when a user access to my script app, permissions are: "...edit and delete a calendar...", but I need only to read it. Should be possible to change it? 
I would like this scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar from the scope array, because it gives you read/write access. Change it in the manifest, then try to run the application again and you should be asked to authorize again (with the new scopes).